# React input binding to state vs local variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking at a tutorial for binding input in react with state. What I don't understand is why do I need to bind it to the state vs just a local vairable since it won't cause renders.

In my case I have a login form, in the tutorial it is sending message form. The idea is that the value is send to the App.js(parent) on submit using inverse data flow. It looks like this:

```
class Login extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            username: ''
        };
        this.login = this.login.bind(this)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }
    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            username: e.target.value
        });
    }
    //here I make a post request and then I set the user in app.js
    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(username)
        }).then(data =>  data.json())
          .then(data => {
              this.props.setUser(data)
              this.setState({
                  username: ''
              })
          }
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <section>
                <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
                    <input placeholder="username" 
                         onChange={this.changeInput} type="text"
                         value={this.state.username}/>
                </form>
            </section>
        )
    }
```

Is there a reason to use setState vs just a local variable which won't cause a rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to, you could make it work without ever storing username in the state. All you have to do is listen for a submit event and fetch the input value at that time, using a ref.

```js
class Login extends Component {
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.refs.username.value)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input ref="username" type="text" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

However the usual way to do that with React is to store the input value in the state and update the state every time the value change. This is called a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and it ensures that the input value and the state are always consistent with each other.

```js
class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
          username: ''
      };
  }

  handleChange(e) {
      this.setState({
          username: e.target.value
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input onChange={e => this.setState({ username: e.target.value })} type="text" value={this.state.username} />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Among other things, it makes things easier to validate the input value or modify it if you need. For instance, you could enforce uppercase by converting the state to uppercase whenever the state changes.

Comment: Is this also true for my case? As i am not doing any modification on user input nor I am chaning the username from outside is it still considered good to do it with state?

Comment: Yeah I would recommend it rather than playing with refs, the cost of the re-rendering will be insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the input field has to change to the new value, that is why for the on change event you set the state to the next event value. If you don't set state, the value will be the same even though it is entered by user.

Hope this helps, 
Happy Learning.

Comment: Not really because the html value is the actual value of the input that is why you are getting e.target.value because the value is already the input you have written. I think it is set again to it so it does a render at the right place.